# Including models from a findOne query in Sequelize returns error

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to get a venue by it's ID from the database using Sequelize as an ORM. I've set up the models in a belongsTo association. So 1 venue can have 1 phone number as well as 1 address. I did read the documentation of Sequelize located on their website but without finding a fix for this issue. Below I've provided you with the Query, the error message and the way that the models are connected with each other.

This is the query:

```
function findById(id) {
  return this.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    include: [
      {
        model: models.Address,
        as: "venue_address"
      },
      {
        model: models.PhoneNumber,
        as: "phone_number"
      }
    ]
  }).then((venue) => {
    if (!venue) {
      return utils.createError(404, `Venue with id ${id} does not exist`);
    }
    return venue;
  });
}
```

Sequelize is returning the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTableName' of undefined
    at Function._validateIncludedElement (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:465:30)
    at options.include.options.include.map.include (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:395:37)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function._validateIncludedElements (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:390:39)
    at Promise.try.then.then (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1576:14)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:756:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:717:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:697:5)
Unhandled rejection Error: Transaction cannot be rolled back because it has been finished with state: commit
    at Transaction.rollback (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/sequelize/lib/transaction.js:85:35)
    at models.Address.createAddress.then.catch (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/server/routes/venue.js:57:13)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/kevin/Tabbs/API-Mysql/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:756:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:717:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:697:5)
```

The models are associated like this:

```
models.Venue.belongsTo(models.PhoneNumber, {
      as: "phone_number",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: { allowNull: false }
    });
    models.Venue.belongsTo(models.Address, {
      as: "venue_address",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
      foreignKey: { allowNull: false }
    });
```

This is what I am receiving back when I do not include anything:

[image]

Appreciate all the help fixing this issue!

Comment: is your database initialized? do the tables exist?

Comment: Yes it's all working pretty decent, when I remove the includes the query works as I expected to. The only problem is that instead of id's I want the full table include in the object that returns back.

Comment: @weagle08 have a look at this other query which is executed on the employee model. https://www.pastiebin.com/5ae4cbcc4ad05 here it works like charm

Comment: Any idea how this is possible @weagle08 ?

Comment: @weagle08 the issue is that when I try to do -> const models = require('./') because its the same directory it gives undefined for models. So basically that error is because of the import. How can I require the same folder ?

Comment: to be able to do const models = require('./') you must have an index.js file in the immediate directory you are trying to include.

Comment: here is a sample index.js i am using in a current project:
https://www.pastiebin.com/5ae51a2e725ef

Comment: here is an example of one of my models: https://www.pastiebin.com/5ae51ab98aa85

Comment: @weagle08 I do have both files (similar) just from the docs of sequelize.

Comment: @weagle08 Have a look at the index.js file in the ./models folder: https://pastebin.com/NtMnxgMC

Comment: see answer, I think I see your issue... you'd think the library would handle relation ordering for you, but this does not seem to be the case. Anyways try my suggestion and see if that fixes it

Answer (score 1):

I think your tables are being initialized out of order. If you see my example here: [Example Index File](https://www.pastiebin.com/5ae51a2e725ef) you will notice that I have an array of models in a specific order which I loop through to initialize the tables. I think you have a foreign key dependency that is not being initialized before the association is being created and this is why you are seeing this error.

Short answer: You need to make sure foreign key dependencies are initialized before the dependent relation.

Comment: I'll have a look ;)